# Blocking all UI using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, blocking

How to block all UI things in a webpage until all JavaScript files including jquery.js are loaded completely. Is there any possibility to do it using only JavaScript?

Comment: What are "all UI things"?

Comment: You should clarify things in details.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Answer (score 2):

You can add a css mask with z-index set to higher than all your other ui elements on the page

In your page

```
<body>
<div class="mask"></div>
..
..
</body>
```

CSS

```
.mask {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   background: #666;
   overflow: hidden;
   opacity: 0.7;
   z-index: 99;
}
```

Once your jQuery is loaded, hide this mask.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.mask').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add some kind of this snippet at the very top of you body:

```
<div class="loading-overlay" id="loading">
    <div class="loading">Loading..</div>
</div>
```

and this styles inline in HEAD:

```
<style>.loading-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    z-index: 1000;
}
.loading {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}</style>
```

Then after *all* javascript files execute this code:

```
document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
```

Make sure `z-index` property of the overlay is high enough to cover everything on the page.

However this solution is not reliable if some of your heavy scripts are loaded asynchronously.

#### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ucPLW/

Answer (score 1):

Statically listing the script tags in the head will ensure they are loaded before the DOM. This has been the case for as long as I can remember.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- insert your script tags here -->
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- your DOM here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Its recommended to load the scripts at the bottom of the page instead so I'm not sure your motivations for this.

Answer (score 0):

If by "UI Things," you mean the DOM, then you can put your javascript either at the end of your html like so:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
<body>

<script>
     // This javascript will execute after the HTML has loaded
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if you want to use JQuery then you can put your UI code in a document ready function like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      // This javascript will also execute after the HTML has loaded
 });
```

Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$(window).load()` event for your code since this happens after the page is fully loaded and all the code in the various `$(document).ready()` handlers have finished running.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  //your code here
});
```